# Removing values between 100000000-199999999

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to modify the following code to delete everything with the value 1xxxxxxxx and 3xxxxxxxx (so, 100000001, 100000002, etc) but my knowledge of SQL isn't perfect. Is there anybody who can help me with modifying this script?

```
SET @increment_id = '100000001';

SELECT *
FROM `sales_flat_quote_address_item`
WHERE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`.`quote_address_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `address_id` 
        FROM `sales_flat_quote_address` 
        WHERE `sales_flat_quote_address`.`quote_id` IN (
        SELECT `entity_id`
            FROM `sales_flat_quote`
            WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` = @increment_id
            )
    );

DELETE  
FROM `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`
WHERE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`.`address_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `address_id` 
        FROM `sales_flat_quote_address` 
        WHERE `sales_flat_quote_address`.`quote_id` IN (
        SELECT `entity_id`
            FROM `sales_flat_quote`
            WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` = @increment_id
            )
    );



DELETE 
FROM `sales_flat_quote_address`
WHERE `sales_flat_quote_address`.`quote_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_flat_quote`
        WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` = @increment_id
    );


DELETE FROM `sales_flat_quote_item_option`
WHERE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`.`item_id`  IN ( 
    SELECT `item_id` 
        FROM `sales_flat_quote_item` 
        WHERE `sales_flat_quote_item`.`quote_id` IN (
        SELECT `entity_id`
            FROM `sales_flat_quote`
            WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` = @increment_id
            )
    );


DELETE FROM `sales_flat_quote_item`
WHERE `sales_flat_quote_item`.`quote_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_flat_quote`
        WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` = @increment_id
    );


DELETE FROM `sales_flat_quote_payment`
WHERE `sales_flat_quote_payment`.`quote_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_flat_quote`
        WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` = @increment_id
    );


DELETE FROM `sales_flat_quote`
WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` = @increment_id;


DELETE FROM `sales_order_datetime`
WHERE `sales_order_datetime`.`entity_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_order`
        WHERE `sales_order`.`increment_id` = @increment_id
    );


DELETE FROM `sales_order_decimal`
WHERE `sales_order_decimal`.`entity_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_order`
        WHERE `sales_order`.`increment_id` = @increment_id
    );

DELETE FROM `sales_order_int`
WHERE `sales_order_int`.`entity_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_order`
        WHERE `sales_order`.`increment_id` = @increment_id
    );

DELETE FROM `sales_order_text`
WHERE `sales_order_text`.`entity_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_order`
        WHERE `sales_order`.`increment_id` = @increment_id
    );


DELETE FROM `sales_order_varchar`
WHERE `sales_order_varchar`.`entity_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_order`
        WHERE `sales_order`.`increment_id` = @increment_id
    );

DELETE FROM `sales_order_entity_datetime`
WHERE `sales_order_entity_datetime`.`entity_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_order_entity`
        WHERE `sales_order_entity`.`increment_id` = @increment_id
    );


DELETE FROM `sales_order_entity_decimal`
WHERE `sales_order_entity_decimal`.`entity_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_order_entity`
        WHERE `sales_order_entity`.`increment_id` = @increment_id
    );

DELETE FROM `sales_order_entity_int`
WHERE `sales_order_entity_int`.`entity_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_order_entity`
        WHERE `sales_order_entity`.`increment_id` = @increment_id
    );

DELETE FROM `sales_order_entity_text` 
WHERE `sales_order_entity_text`.`entity_id` IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_order_entity`
        WHERE `sales_order_entity`.`increment_id` = @increment_id
    );

DELETE FROM `sales_order_entity_varchar`
WHERE `sales_order_entity_varchar`.`entity_id`  IN ( 
    SELECT `entity_id`
        FROM `sales_order_entity`
        WHERE `sales_order_entity`.`increment_id` = @increment_id
    );

DELETE FROM `sales_order_entity`
WHERE `sales_order_entity`.`increment_id` = @increment_id;

DELETE FROM `sales_order`
WHERE `sales_order`.`increment_id` = @increment_id;
```

Comment: Since you have InnoDB as a tag, do all these tables have some or other `FOREIGN KEY`? If yes, what value have you set for `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE`?

Comment: That correct.  Instead of explicitly attempting to delete all these related children, you could just delete the parent and allow ON DELETE CASCADE behavior to delete all the related row in all the related tables.  There's probably no need for all these explicit deletes... and , of course, use WHERE x BETWEEN y AND z logic, not a loop.

Comment: For the range to be **3xxxxxxxx** shouldn't the exit numeral be **2999999999**

Comment: 19 tables describing each order (at least potentially)?  That's quite a lot.  The set of tables `sales_order_entity_{varchar,text,int,decimal,datetime}` leave me puzzled, too.  But basically, each `WHERE sales_order_entity.increment_id = @increment_id` needs to become a range expression `WHERE sales_order_entity.increment_id BETWEEN 100000000 AND 199999999`.  If you want to do the 3-series numbers in the same expression, add `OR sales_order_entity.increment_id BETWEEN 300000000 AND 399999999` too.  Note that the BETWEEN AND range includes both end values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following script to delete all records start with 1 or 3:

```
DELETE 
FROM 'sales_flat_quote_address_item'
WHERE
'sales_flat_quote_address_item'.'quote_address_id' like '1%'
OR 
'sales_flat_quote_address_item'.'quote_address_id' like '3%';
```

Comment: Sorry, the answer is not correct for two reasons: 1. it will match `1`, '10', '100', etc., and 2. The `OR` clause will preclude the query from using any indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` = @increment_id
```

to

```
WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` BETWEEN 100000000 AND 199999999
```

WAIT! The title says `100000000-199999999`, but the question says `1xxxxxxxx and 3xxxxxxxx`, so if it's the latter then change it to:

```
WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` BETWEEN 100000000 AND 399999999
```

or, you could choose to use the `REGEXP` operator instead:

```
WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` REGEXP '^[123][[:digit:]]{8}'
```

Comment: This for every WHERE line? So.

    WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` BETWEEN 100000000 AND 199999999
    WHERE `sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id` BETWEEN 100000000 AND 199999999
etc?

Comment: The regex would also delete values such as `1`, `235`, `30` etc.  Probably not what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would advise doing this. But if performance is not a concern you can use:

```
...
WHERE LEFT(`sales_order`.`increment_id`, 1) = 1 
    AND RIGHT(`sales_order`.`increment_id`, 8) BETWEEN 0 and 99999999
```

and

```
...
WHERE LEFT(`sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id`, 1) = 1 
    AND RIGHT(`sales_flat_quote`.`reserved_order_id`, 8) BETWEEN 0 and 99999999
```

This is assuming the fields are 9 characters in length. It will match the left most value to `1` and check the range of the right set.

Perhaps you may also want to use a transaction in case something goes wrong?

Comment: MySQL will not use indexes, but instead do full table scans, if you use functions on the left of the equality operator. I don't see that this is needed in the case, and will only hurt performance.